# View/Modify word document online?

Tags: documents

We are currently using the Interop for word document maniplulation's like merge of fields to word template docs and also some macro code which on download of the word file to the cient system does some calculation and gets updated on the server !

We need to change this .
Is there any way like view/modifying a word document online(Web) make changes to doc and get it saved to the server ?

Regards,
Francis P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Docs

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Microsoft Office 365 API.
[Office 365 API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)